# Fast click on jquery animate with callback

Tags: jquery, callback, jquery-animate

Here is the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/kezb6dqp/1/)

```
<div id="button" class="overlay-down">click</div>
    $(function () {
        $('#button').on('click', function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('overlay-down')) {
                $(this).removeClass('overlay-down').addClass('overlay-up');
                $('#text').stop(true, true).animate({opacity: 0}, 800, function() { // fade #text
                    $('#overlay').stop(true, true).slideUp(500); // then slideup #overlay
                });
            } else
            if($(this).hasClass('overlay-up')) {
                $(this).removeClass('overlay-up').addClass('overlay-down');
                $('#overlay').stop(true, true).slideDown(500, function(){ // #overlay come back
                    $('#text').stop(true, true).animate({opacity: 1}, 800); // then #text come back
                });
            }
        });
    })
```

When clicks are made quickly, the animation goes wrong-  overlay slides up,but text doesn't fade out.

Each time I click the button, I want to keep the in progress animate run to finish callback animate (not stop the animate, not go to end), ignore button click before in progress animate finish.

I have tried is(':animated') detect and remove stop(true, true), it works, but any other simple and better way to do this?

Also, in the above code, if I need to use stop(), i need to add stop() to every animate element? Above code I have to add 4 stop(), is it right?

thanks you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can remove the click event, when you already have clicked it, untill the `animation` completes, then you can reAdd the click event, so you are ready for next animation.

See this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/kezb6dqp/2/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#button').on('click', fun);
})

function fun() {
  $('#button').off('click', fun);
  if ($(this).hasClass('overlay-down')) {
    $(this).removeClass('overlay-down').addClass('overlay-up');
    $('#text').stop(true, true).animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 800, function() { // fade #text
      $('#overlay').stop(true, true).slideUp(500, function() {
        $('#button').on('click', fun);
      }); // then slideup #overlay
    });
  } else
  if ($(this).hasClass('overlay-up')) {
    $(this).removeClass('overlay-up').addClass('overlay-down');
    $('#overlay').stop(true, true).slideDown(500, function() { // #overlay come back
      $('#text').stop(true, true).animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 800, function() {
        $('#button').on('click', fun);
      }); // then #text come back
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
#text {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
#button {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="overlay"></div>
  <div id="text">
    <p>text here text here</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="button" class="overlay-down">click</div>
```

Comment: very useful, this code will ignore the click before animate finish, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't have the problem regarding fast click.

```
$(function () {
$('#button').on('click', function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('overlay-down')) {
        $(this).removeClass('overlay-down').addClass('overlay-up');
        $('#text').stop(true, true).animate({opacity: 0}, 500);
        $('#overlay').stop(true, true).slideUp(800);
    } else
    if($(this).hasClass('overlay-up')) {
        $(this).removeClass('overlay-up').addClass('overlay-down');

        $('#overlay').stop(true, true).slideDown(500);
        $('#text').stop(true, true).animate({opacity: 1}, 800);
    }
});
})
```

Comment: its work too, the animate not go wrong now, thank you so much :)